# express can't serve static file for child ejs file

Tags: express, ejs

express version is 3.2.5, ejs version is 0.8.4

I want to serve `stylesheets/style.css`

I am doing this way in `app.js`

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(app.router);

  // render article.ejs
  app.get('/u/:name/:day/:title', function(req,res){
    Post.getOne(req.params.name, req.params.day, req.params.title, function(err, post){
      if(err){
        req.flash('error',err);
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
      res.render('article',{
        title: req.params.title,
        post: post,
        user: req.session.user,
        success: req.flash('success').toString(),
        error: req.flash('error').toString()
      });
    });
  });
```

my structure is `header.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

`article.ejs` content is

```
<%- include header %>
<p class="info">
  author：<a href="/u/<%= post.name %>"><%= post.name %></a> | 
  date：<%= post.time.minute %>
 </p>
 <p><%- post.post %></p>
<%- include comment %>
<%- include footer %>
```

When I access `http://localhost:3000/`

```
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 9ms
```

while access `localhost:3000/u/username/date/postname`

```
GET /u/username/date/stylesheets/style.css 404 10ms
```

why it shows this `/u/username/date/stylesheets/style.css` directory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You don't start your stylesheets path with a /. So it's loading "stylesheets/style.css" relative to whichever HTML file requested it.

Comment: i tried what your said `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/style.css">` it still loads the relative path

Comment: That's because ./ is a relative path. Do /stylesheets/style.css. That's an absolute path